# Incorrect result of loop

Tags: javascript

I study Java Script and faced the problem that during looping the result of last cycle is inserted not at the last but at first.

My Code:

```js
//Determine annuity
const annuity = document.querySelector('#annuityType');
let payment = document.querySelector('#cashFlowType');

function showAnnuity() {
  payment.innerHTML = ``;
  payment = document.querySelector('#cashFlowType');
  payment.innerHTML = `<label for="annuity">Сума ануїтету </label><input id="annuity" name="annuity" type="text"><br><br>`;
}
annuity.onclick = showAnnuity;

//Determine different cash flows
const different = document.querySelector('#differentType');

function showDifferentType() {
  payment.innerHTML = ``;
  payment = document.querySelector('#cashFlowPeriods');
  let newPayment;
  for (let i = 1; i <= document.querySelector('#period').value; i++) {
    if (i == 1) {
      newPayment = document.querySelector('#cashFlowOne');
      newPayment.innerHTML = `<label for="diffCashFlow">Income for period <span id="periodDiff">1 </span></label><input id="diffCashFlow" name="differentCashFlow" type="text"><br><br>`;
    } else {
      let np = newPayment.cloneNode(true);
      np.id = i;
      document.querySelector('#periodDiff').innerHTML = i + " ";
      payment.append(np);
    }
  }
}
different.onclick = showDifferentType;
```

```html
<div>
  <label for="period">Строк проекту (у роках)</label>
  <input id="period" name="period" type="text">
</div>
<div>
  <p>What kind of payment?</p>
  <label for="annuityType">Annuity</label>
  <input id="annuityType" name="cashFlowType" type="radio">
  <label for="differentType">Different payments</label>
  <input id="differentType" name="cashFlowType" type="radio">
</div><br>
<div id="cashFlowType"></div>
<div id="cashFlowPeriods">
  <div id="cashFlowOne"><span id="periodDiff"></span></div>
</div>
```

For example, when I insert 5 into input "period", the sequence of results of loop is next:

Income for period 5

Income for period 1

Income for period 2

Income for period 3

Income for period 4

I tried to researched the reason but didn't find it. I will be grateful for any help.

Comment: `document.querySelector('#period').value` is a string, comparing strings and numbers might give you unexpected results.

Comment: What's happening is that you're duplicating the element, but then setting the *original* element's innerHTML via the query selector. The next time you duplicate, you are copying that *original* element which now has the changed innerHTML. If you inspect the `id` of each element, you will see that the one with `id="2"` says "Income for period 1".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign the `innerHTML` of the cloned node, not the original node after you cloned it.

Since IDs shouldn't be repeated, change `id="periodDiff" to` class="periodDiff".

```js
//Determine annuity
const annuity = document.querySelector('#annuityType');
let payment = document.querySelector('#cashFlowType');

function showAnnuity() {
  payment.innerHTML = ``;
  payment = document.querySelector('#cashFlowType');
  payment.innerHTML = `<label for="annuity">Сума ануїтету </label><input id="annuity" name="annuity" type="text"><br><br>`;
}
annuity.onclick = showAnnuity;

//Determine different cash flows
const different = document.querySelector('#differentType');

function showDifferentType() {
  payment.innerHTML = ``;
  payment = document.querySelector('#cashFlowPeriods');
  let newPayment;
  for (let i = 1; i <= document.querySelector('#period').value; i++) {
    if (i == 1) {
      newPayment = document.querySelector('#cashFlowOne');
      newPayment.innerHTML = `<label for="diffCashFlow">Income for period <span class="periodDiff">1 </span></label><input class="diffCashFlow" name="differentCashFlow" type="text"><br><br>`;
    } else {
      let np = newPayment.cloneNode(true);
      np.id = i;
      np.querySelector(".periodDiff").innerHTML = i + " ";
      payment.append(np);
    }
  }
}
different.onclick = showDifferentType;
```

```html
<div>
  <label for="period">Строк проекту (у роках)</label>
  <input id="period" name="period" type="text">
</div>
<div>
  <p>What kind of payment?</p>
  <label for="annuityType">Annuity</label>
  <input id="annuityType" name="cashFlowType" type="radio">
  <label for="differentType">Different payments</label>
  <input id="differentType" name="cashFlowType" type="radio">
</div><br>
<div id="cashFlowType"></div>
<div id="cashFlowPeriods">
  <div id="cashFlowOne"><span id="periodDiff"></span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. But when i press the radio button with id "differentType" repeatedly it cast exception `Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML')`. Have you any idea the reason of that?

Comment: It's because you're reusing the variable `payment`. The first time, `payment = document.querySelector('#cashFlowType');`. But then you redefine it to `payment = document.querySelector('#cashFlowPeriods');`. Then you do `payment.innerHTML = '';`, so `#cashFlowOne` is removed.

Comment: It would be better to use a template that isn't in the DIV that you're appending to. That way you can empty the DIV without destroying the template. You also wouldn't need to special-case the `i == 1` iteration.

Answer (score 1):

you need to create elements using `document.createElement` instead of relying on building it using `.innerHTML` which can be risky if misused.

```js
//Determine annuity
const annuity = document.querySelector('#annuityType');
let payment = document.querySelector('#cashFlowType');
function showAnnuity(){
    payment.innerHTML = ``;
    payment = document.querySelector('#cashFlowType');
    payment.innerHTML = `<label for="annuity">Сума ануїтету </label><input id="annuity" name="annuity" type="text"><br><br>`;
}
annuity.onclick = showAnnuity;

//Determine different cash flows
const different = document.querySelector('#differentType');
function showDifferentType(){
    payment.innerHTML = ``;
    payment = document.querySelector('#cashFlowPeriods');
    let newPayment;
    let html = '';
    for(let i = 1; i <= document.querySelector('#period').value; i++){
        let label = document.createElement('label');
        let input = document.createElement('input');
        let br = document.createElement('br');
        
        input.id = `periodDiff${i}`;
        label.htmlFor = input.id;
        label.innerText = `Income for period ${i} `;
        payment.append(label);
        payment.append(input);
        payment.append(br);
    }
}
different.onclick = showDifferentType;
```

```html
<div>
    <label for="period">Строк проекту (у роках)</label>
    <input id="period" name="period" type="text">
</div>
<div>
  <p>What kind of payment?</p>
  <label for="annuityType">Annuity</label>
  <input id="annuityType" name="cashFlowType" type="radio">
  <label for="differentType">Different payments</label>
  <input id="differentType" name="cashFlowType" type="radio">
</div><br>
<div id="cashFlowType"></div>
<div id="cashFlowPeriods"><div id="cashFlowOne">  <span id="periodDiff"></span></div></div>
<div>
```

Comment: I tried your code and the order is correct but the inputs are stuck. I assume the command `payment.append(br);` doesn't work. I tried to use it repeatedly but without results. Have you any idea how to make break between inputs?